# MATLAB: Write a function called MVP that takes in an array and returns the most valuable player

Tags: matlab

I need help with a hard bonus question using MATLAB.

Question: You are given an array of structures named Stats.  Each structure contains the following fields: BA, HomeRuns, Errors. Write a function that takes in that array and returns the MVP of the season.  The MVP is defined as the player with the highest batting average(BA) given he has at least 25 home runs and at the most 5 errors.

Comment: Use find() to pre-filter candidates and max() to get the MVP from those. I didnt check if this actually works, though, so this is only a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The following should give you some ideas:

```
  [Stats.HomeRuns]
  ind = find( x > 25 );
  max([Stats(ind).BA])
```